# What is the best way to add an API key to Google App Engine as an environment variable?

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an App Engine that runs a flask app which hits an API endpoint and that needs an API key. I wanted to add it to an environment variable in the `app.yaml` file but then it would be visible in git.
I do not want to use secrets manager as this App Engine will be triggered a lot, meaning a lot of cost will be incurred that I want to avoid. So [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252930/how-to-add-environment-variables-to-google-app-engine) doesn't work.
Is there any way I can add an environment variable to the app engine like how we can for Cloud Function and Cloud Run?

Comment: All solutions there don't tell you how you can set it as an environment variable. They mostly seem to be a variation of the Secrets Manager solution.

Comment: There is a third-party solution for this: [environment variable compiler](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/gae-environment-variable-compiler)

Comment: @Nissan. If you downvote my answer, no problem, just let me know what's the problem with it. Why does it not match your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't primarily want, Secret Manager is the solution!

Firstly, Secret Manager is not [so expensive to access secret ($0.03 for 10,000 access)](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/pricing). That means you need to start 10,000 app engine instances to pay only $0.03!

Why so few? Because, when you read 1 time the secret, your API Key, you can keep it in memory in a global variable (singleton pattern). Like that, Load it only once at instance start, and then use it many time, up to the instance is offloaded.

*Note: If you start 300 instances per day, other costs will be much more higher that the $0.03 of Secret Manager*

Comment: Hey, I wasn't the one who downvoted the answer.  
It's just that I wanted to avoid more API calls in my program as much as possible because it needs to be very performant. Every millisecond matters.

Comment: Is the performance more important than the performances? You ask the secret only once, at startup, not at every calls. In addition, is performance matters don't use a serverless product that scale to 0. In addition, you don't manage the network layers, routing and security, that are, most of the time, less efficient that a raw IaaS infra. If millisecond matters, you design should be wrong!

Comment: Hmmm are you saying App Engine is not the way to go then? I do agree with your suggestion to ask the secret only once at boot. That is what I ended up doing at the end.

Comment: If you target the performance, having a service that start and stop at any time, and therefore to have few request with high latency (due to instance start, also named cold start) it's not the good solution!

Comment: The traffic on the service will be continuous throughout 24 hours, and I can set the minimum instances to 1. Wouldn't that negate the cold start problem?